# Mismatch between ADL and actual iPad build

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, air, mismatch

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I am trying to build an iPad app with as3 and air.
The problem is that i am trying to build for the retina iPad and when im debugging on the computer via ADL it looks one way when im building and are debugging on the iPad its being scaled up and the top of the iPad estimate is 50 pixel isnt used. 
It looks like its being pressed down on the screen.

So my question is, why is there a difference between the two debugging layouts?

Thanks in advance

Jonas

Answer (score 0):

If you debug it locally you have to add a "device" for the Retina iPads.

Comment: I really added an iPad retina as build device.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running into a scale mode issue, believe you'll need something like the following if you don't want the swf to be scaled but instead to use every pixel provided:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; 
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

**References**

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e31.html#WS0D75B487-23B9-402d-A52D-CB3C4CEB9EE4

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html

Comment: Thanks. But that is already in my code. I tried adding this.scale = etc. But it only scales it down to really small and i couldn't scale it up by changing the scale factor ie. 0.5, 0.9 etc.

And furthermore its like its pushing my stage down by estimated 50 pixel before it starts. Everything is set to start in x = 0 and y = 0.
I really don't get it. I can provide full code example if it helps anything?

Im building for portrait mode if its needed.

Thanks in advance! :)